# Why is JavaScript from Doubleclick run when Google Tag Manager is installed?

Tags: google-tag-manager, privacy, doubleclick-ad-exchange

I recently reinstalled NoScript and noticed that a web page for a business I'm involved in (which is on the fringe of the financial industry) wants to run javascript from DoubleClick.  There are no links to Doubleclick, and the webmaster was unaware of this behaviour - I suspect there is an iframe with javascript to Google Tag Manager (which I understand is used for analytics), but this has not proven trivial to confirm.

I'm postulating that this iframe in turn calls Doubleclick, and that Doubleclick info is used for targetting adverts - ie visits to our site are tracked and used to tune advertising.  Does that sound correct?   If so, is there a way to disable Doubleclick tracking short of removing reliance on Tag Manager ?

Also, am I correct in my understanding that Doubleclick itself does not offer anything of value to people visiting the website or owners of a website who are not interested in making money off online advertising, and that they don't have a great privacy policy ?

Comment: If you can get access to their GTM account you will be able to see yourself. It does sound very likely though. After all, GTM is meant to handle all your tags, no only GA. You are right in your assumption. DC doesn't add any other value to your visitors.

Comment: Are you running advertisements on the site such as AdSense?

Comment: @stephenostermiller No, As I understand it it's there for analytics only.